# JavaScript Pint a file DYMO

Tags: javascript, printing, vbscript, dymo

I have this script in Visual Basic:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript>
        Sub DrukujKodKreskowy()
        Dim DymoAddIn, DymoLabel, pole, kod
        Set DymoAddIn = CreateObject("DYMO.DymoAddIn")
        Set DymoLabel = CreateObject("DYMO.DymoLabels")
        DymoAddIn.Open "c:\Ceramika_11352.LWL"
        kod=document.forms("form1").item("txtBarkod").value
        pole="KOD"
        DymoLabel.SetField pole,kod
        DymoAddIn.Print 1, TRUE
        DymoAddIn.Quit
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

I want to write the same script in JavaScript because I want to be able to open it in Chrome. I tried, but it doesn't work.

This it script:

```
    <script src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest"
        if (label.getAddressObjectCount() == 0)
                {
                    alert("Selected label does not have an address object on it. Select another label");

                }
                var printer = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
                var label = dymo.label.framework.openFile('C:\Ceramika_11352.LWL');

                label.print(printer.value);
 <script>
```

Comment: "I tried, but it doesn't work." So what. What is your question? What does not work? What have you tried to diagnose the problem?

Comment: should the script src be `http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js`? I think you are missing the `*.js` file extension.